# my "useInterval" can't let the timer count properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to make a timer.
My code is

```js
export default function Test() {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0)
    
    function CountUp() {
        setCount(count + 1);
    }
    useInterval(() => {
        CountUp();
    }, 1000, count)

    return (
        <div>
            {count}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Here is `useInterval`

```
function useInterval(callback, delay) {
     const ref = useRef()
     useEffect(() => {
         ref.current = callback;
     })
     useEffect(() => {
         const timerId = setInterval(ref.current, delay); 
         return () => {
             clearInterval(timerId);
         }
     }, [delay])
 }


const timerId = setInterval(()=>{ ref.current() }, delay);
```

These code does not work. The `count` only increased once.

But if I change the code `const timerId = setInterval(ref.current, delay);` to `const timerId = setInterval(() => { ref.current() }, delay);`.

It works!
I can not understand why the code I wrote is wrong.
Could you please tell me why?

Comment: Why do you think it's wrong?  When you debug, how does it fail?  How does it differ from your "correct code"?  Please provide details about the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good evening, I think it may be connected with the javascript reference system.

Write

```
const timerId = setInterval(() => ref.current(), delay);
```

it will be better ;)

In short, when you write like

```
const timerId = setInterval(ref.current, delay)
```

you pass a reference to property to ref.current and after success executing, your ref.current remove his reference to property. I can advice you use closures. () => ref.current(), it can guarantee you what reference always will exist.

Answer (score 0):

You want to give an empty array as second argument to useEffect so that the function is only run once after the initial render.

Because of how closures work, this will make the counter variable always reference the initial value. You can use the function version of setCounter instead to always get the correct value.

Example

```
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setCounter(counter => counter + 1);
    }, 1000);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, []);

  return <h1>{counter}</h1>;
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0-alpha.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```